# Feedback Button on Right side that handles scrollbar?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a feedback button that is on the right hand side.

```
   <button className="feedback-button">Feedback</button>

.feedback-button {
  height: 40px;
  border: solid 3px #CCCCCC;
  background: #333;
  width: 100px;
  line-height: 32px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  font-weight: 600;
  color: white;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 17px;
  position: fixed;
  right: -40px;
  top: 45%;
  font-family: "Roboto", helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

However this does not factor when a scrollbar is shown then feedback button gets overlapped with the scrollbar.

I would like it to be beside the scrollbar but when no scrollbar is shown it adjusts so it is beside the end of the page.

edit

[image]

Comment: Try changing this `right: -40px;`

Comment: yes, I been playing around with that but if I change that when no scrollbar is shown then it will have a gab between the edge.

Comment: i dont find any gap ? can you send screenshot of it ?

Comment: No there is no gab, but it is under the scrollbar and when I adjust the "right" to say -30px to move it beside the scrollbar but when there is no scrollbar now there is a gab.

Comment: Is there a specific browser you are getting this error on? Most browsers accommodate for the scrollbar as far as I know, so this code should work.

Comment: this is on latest version of chrome, and the scrollbar is on a div

Comment: The code in your question is working fine for me. I'm guessing the parent element has some kind of styles that are counteracting it.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that some elements in the parent can be collapsed and thus the scrollbar disappears and this is when the gap is shown(maybe if there was no scrollbar on load it would calculate properly?)

Comment: does the parent has a static height? If it's calculated this might causes the problem. You could check the overflow css parameter on the elements that have no scroll set. I assume you use width 100%. Have you tried replacing it with 100vw on the element that should cover the entire screen? Also is your box-sizing set to border-box?